# How $min and $max works internally on an embedded document?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say, I initially have the following documents in DB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d932facf2e6411a68a145e8"),
    "name" : "mechanic",
    "value" : {
        "a" : 1,
        "b" : 2
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d932facf2e6411a68a145e9"),
    "name" : "mechanic",
    "value" : {
        "a" : 2,
        "b" : 1
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d932facf2e6411a68a145ea"),
    "name" : "mechanic",
    "value" : {
        "a" : 0,
        "b" : 3
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9332eff2e6411a68a145ec"),
    "name" : "mechanic",
    "value" : {
        "a" : 0,
        "b" : 2
    }
}
```

When I run the following query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ { $group:{ "_id":"$name", "min_doc":{ $min:"$value" } } } ]).pretty()
```

It returns:

```
{ "_id" : "mechanic", "min_doc" : { "a" : 0, "b" : 2 } }
```

Which seems, its comparing the keys of sub-document `value` one by one i.e. find minimum 'a', if multiple documents have minimum 'a', then find minimum 'b'.

But then, I add one more document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d933330f2e6411a68a145ed"),
    "name" : "mechanic",
    "value" : {
        "b" : 1,
        "a" : 0
    }
}
```

And it returns the same output. But the last document has the lowest 'a' and 'b'.

How it's working internally?

Comment: @Sharma good question, even I was searching for something which can help me inspecting my queries in MongoDB, but could not find anything. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/

> $min compares both value and type, using the specified BSON comparison order for values of different types.

As `$value` is Object, Mongo follows this instructions:

MongoDB’s comparison of BSON objects uses the following order:

1. Recursively compare key-value pairs in the order that they appear within the BSON object.
2. Compare the key field names.
3. If the key field names are equal, compare the field values.
4. If the field values are equal, compare the next key/value pair (return to step 1). An object without further pairs is less than an object with further pairs.

**Explanation**

1. MongoDB picks 1st stored object key from all documents.
2. Keys are compared. For stings, binary comparison is used. If equals, next step
3. Value are compared. For stings, binary comparison is used. If equals, next step
4. Repeat step 1 unless `an object without further pairs is less than an object with further pairs`.

================================================================

**What does it mean "in the order that they appear within the BSON object"**

Let's change a bit: (Key order)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d932facf2e6411a68a145e8"),
    "name" : "mechanic",
    "value" : {
        "b" : 0, <-- 1st key
        "a" : 0  <-- 2nd key
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d932facf2e6411a68a145e9"),
    "name" : "mechanic",
    "value" : {
        "a" : 100, <-- 1st key
        "b" : 100  <-- 2nd key
    }
}
```

Logically, min value is `{"b" : 0, "a" : 0}`, but it depends the order of keys are stored.

As `a` less then `b`, min value is:

```
{
    "_id" : "mechanic",
    "min_doc" : {
        "a" : 100,
        "b" : 100
    }
}
```

If we change 1st document `a` and `b` order, min value will change:

```
{
    "_id" : "mechanic",
    "min_doc" : {
        "a" : 0,
        "b" : 0
    }
}
```

Source: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#objects